# Сортировка массива

Tags: php

```
$dirct= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/main/';
$hdl=opendir($dirct);
while ($file = readdir($hdl))
if ( ($file!=".")&&($file!=".."))  {

$a[]=$file;
}
closedir($hdl);

foreach ($a as $value) {
echo ("<a href = /main/$value>$value</a><br/>") ;
}
```

Как отсортировать массив `$a` так, чтобы папки были выше файлов и всё в алфавитном порядке? 
С помощью функции `uksort`, а как именно - не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dirs = [];
$files = [];

...

if (($file!=".")&&($file!="..")){
    if(is_dir($file)) $dirs[]=$file;
    else $files[] = $file;
}

//сортировка sort'ом и вывод из $dirs, затем из $files
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию `filesize($file)` для проверки имеем мы дело с категорией или файлом. Ваш пример в этом случае будет выглядеть так:

```
$dirct= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/main/';
$hdl=opendir($dirct);
while ($file = readdir($hdl))
if ( ($file!=".")&&($file!=".."))  {
    if(filesize($file)) $files[]=$file;
    else $dirs[] = $file;
}
closedir($hdl);

usort($files,"strcmp");
//выводим файлы
foreach ($files as $value) {
echo ("<a href = /main/$value>".$value."</a><br/>") ;
}
//выводим директории
usort($dirs,"strcmp");
foreach ($dirs as $value) {
echo ("<a href = /main/$value>".$value."</a><br/>") ;
}
```

еще можно добавить использование функции usort(); Вот так:

```
function mySort($file_a, $file_b){
    //функция для сортировки элементов
    //возвращает: 
    //-1 если $file_a должен быть ниже чем $file_b
    // 1 в обратной ситуации
    // 0 если элементы эквивалентны
        $filesize_a = filesize($file_a);
        $filesize_b = filesize($file_b);
        if (!$filesize_a && !$filesize_b || $filesize_a && $filesize_b) return strcmp($file_a, $file_b);
        else if ($filesize_a) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }

    $dirct= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/main/';
    $hdl=opendir($dirct);
    while ($file = readdir($hdl))
    if ( ($file!=".")&&($file!=".."))  {
        $a[]=$file;
    }
    closedir($hdl);
    usort($a,"mySort");
    foreach ($a as $value) {
        echo ("<a href = /main/".$value.">".$value."</a><br/>") ;
    }
```

Этот код выведет сначала ссылки на файлы, потом на папки. Играясь со значениями возвращаемыми функцией mySort() можно изменять сортировку.